# Mapster: Mapping Properties of different types, No default constructor for type 'CultureInfo', please use 'ConstructUsing' or 'MapWith'

Tags: c#, mapster, dto-mapping

I use [Mapster](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster) with version 7.3.0 and .Net 7.0.1

I have two classes.

```
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; } = default!;

    public string Note { get; set; } = default!;

    public CultureInfo CultureInfo { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class Dto
{
    [Required, StringLength(64)]
    public string Id { get; set; } = default!;

    [Required, StringLength(4096)]
    public string Content { get; set; } = default!;

    [Required, StringLength(1024)]
    public string Note { get; set; } = default!;

    [Required]
    public string CultureName { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

And with mapster config

```
TypeAdapterConfig<Dto, Entity>.NewConfig()
            .Map(entity => entity.CultureInfo, dto => CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(dto.CultureName));
TypeAdapterConfig<Entity, Dto>.NewConfig()
            .Map(dto => dto.CultureName, entity => entity.CultureInfo.Name);
```

Now execute this code

```
//Mapster configuration is applied.

var dto = new Dto
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Content = "this is a test content",
            Note = "for test",
            CultureName = "zh-CN"
        };
        var mLocal = dto.Adapt<Entity>();
```

`var mLocal = dto.Adapt<Entity>();` throws a Mapster.CompileException: Error while compiling.

```
Mapster.CompileException: Error while compiling

Mapster.CompileException
Error while compiling
source=MindOcean.Models.Common.MessageTemplateLocalizerDto
destination=MindOcean.Data.Entities.MessageTemplateLocalizer
type=Map
   at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateMapExpression(CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateMapExpression(TypeTuple tuple, MapType mapType)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateDynamicMapExpression(TypeTuple tuple)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.<GetDynamicMapFunction>b__66_0[TDestination](TypeTuple tuple)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.<>c__DisplayClass55_0`1.<AddToHash>b__0(TypeTuple types)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.AddToHash[T](ConcurrentDictionary`2 hash, TypeTuple key, Func`2 func)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.GetDynamicMapFunction[TDestination](Type sourceType)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapter.Adapt[TDestination](Object source, TypeAdapterConfig config)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapter.Adapt[TDestination](Object source)
   at MindOcean.Test.UnitTest.MapsterTester.TestTwoWay() in /Test/MapsterTester.cs:line 71
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

Mapster.CompileException
Error while compiling
source=System.Globalization.CultureInfo
destination=System.Globalization.CultureInfo
type=Map
   at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateMapExpression(CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateInlineMapExpression(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, MapType mapType, CompileContext context, MemberMapping mapping)
   at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateAdaptExpressionCore(Expression source, Type destinationType, CompileArgument arg, MemberMapping mapping, Expression destination)
   at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateAdaptExpression(Expression source, Type destinationType, CompileArgument arg, MemberMapping mapping, Expression destination)
   at Mapster.Adapters.ClassAdapter.CreateInlineExpression(Expression source, CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateInlineExpressionBody(Expression source, CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateExpressionBody(Expression source, Expression destination, CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateAdaptFunc(CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateMapExpression(CompileArgument arg)

System.InvalidOperationException
No default constructor for type 'CultureInfo', please use 'ConstructUsing' or 'MapWith'
   at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateInstantiationExpression(Expression source, Expression destination, CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.Adapters.ClassAdapter.CreateInstantiationExpression(Expression source, Expression destination, CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateInstantiationExpression(Expression source, CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.Adapters.ClassAdapter.CreateInlineExpression(Expression source, CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateInlineExpressionBody(Expression source, CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateExpressionBody(Expression source, Expression destination, CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateAdaptFunc(CompileArgument arg)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateMapExpression(CompileArgument arg)
```

`No default constructor for type 'CultureInfo', please use 'ConstructUsing' or 'MapWith'`

I tried use MapWith and it worked.

```
TypeAdapterConfig<Dto, Entity>.NewConfig()
     .MapWith(dto => new Entity
     {
         CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(dto.CultureName),
         Id = Guid.Parse(dto.Id),
         Content = dto.Content,
         Note = dto.Note,
     });
TypeAdapterConfig<Entity, Dto>.NewConfig()
            .Map(dto => dto.CultureName, entity => entity.CultureInfo.Name);
```

I prefer `TypeAdapterConfig<Dto, Entity>.NewConfig()` this way. If there are a lot of properties in the `Entity` class, and I only need to configure the `CultureInfo` property, the configuration of the other properties is unnecessary, so I don't have to write so much unnecessary code.`MapWith` is like I'm converting manually and with a lot of unnecessary code.

**I want to know is there an another way rather than `MapWith` to solve this mapster mapping configuration problem?**

Comment: "I tried use MapWith and it worked. but I don't think this is the best way to go." - Why not? What *specific* issue do you have with it? Without knowing what aspect of it you don't like, it's going to be hard to suggest others without thinking you may dislike those options for the same reason.

Comment: I prefer `TypeAdapterConfig<Dto, Entity>. NewConfig()` this way. If there are a lot of properties in the 'Entity' class, and I only need to configure the 'CultureInfo' property, the configuration of the other properties is unnecessary, so I don't have to write so much unnecessary code.`MapWith` is like I'm converting manually and with a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: So all of that should be in the question. (I don't use Mapster myself, so can't help you - but if I *could* think of options, I wouldn't want to spend time describing them without any confidence that it would help you.) Please edit the question to be more specific than "I want to know is there another way" and "I don't think this is the best way to go".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why it does not work, but at least one workaround can be ignoring the member and using after mapping action:

```cs
TypeAdapterConfig<Dto, Entity>.NewConfig()
    .Ignore(e => e.CultureInfo)
    .AfterMapping((d, e) => e.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(d.CultureName));
```

Comment: Smart one! This is a way to solve the problem. I think `config.ForType<string, CultureInfo>().MapWith(name => CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(name));` should work too, but this one is a global configuration.